# elementary doesn't boot anymore (after having tryied to upgrade to Juno)

Tags: release-juno, updates, boot

I at first had an update problem. As I had manually stopped an update (I shut down the computer because the update took too much time), after that updates were blocked by something.

I therefore searched the Internet to look after what was blocking updates. I found :
https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/upgrade-to-elementary-os-juno/
and thought it might fix it.

I tried the upgrade to Juno while trying to solve this update problem.

I typed all the proposed commands as proposed.

As I restarted the computer, there were 1500 available updates for the OS.
I tried to really do these updates from the Appcenter. But I had to interrupt them one more time (the computer was freezing).

After that, elementary OS doesn't boot, even after more than an hour. I once had the following error message while trying to boot :

```
[ 5553.340262] iwl3945 000: 02 : 00 : 0 : Error sending C_POWER_TBL : time out after 500ms.

[ 5553.340262] iwl3945 000: 02 : 00 : 0 : set power fail, ret= -110

[ 5553.340262] iwl3945 000: 02 : 00 : 0 : Queue 4 stuck for 2048 ms.

[ 5553.340262] iwl3945 000: 02 : 00 : 0 : On demand firmware reload

[ 5553.340262] iwl3945 000: 02 : 00 : 0 : BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xa5a5a5a2, s/b 0xf802020

                                                                                  Unable to set up bootstrap uCode : -5

[ 5553.340262] iwl3945 000: 02 : 00 : 0 : BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xa5a5a5a2, s/b 0xf802020

                                                                                  Unable to set up bootstrap uCode : -5

[ 5553.340262] iwl3945 000: 02 : 00 : 0 : BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xa5a5a5a2, s/b 0xf802020

                                                                                  Unable to set up bootstrap uCode : -5

[ 5553.340262] iwl3945 000: 02 : 00 : 0 : BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xa5a5a5a2, s/b 0xf802020

                                                                                  Unable to set up bootstrap uCode : -5

[ 5553.340262] iwl3945 000: 02 : 00 : 0 : BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xa5a5a5a2, s/b 0xf802020

                                                                                  Unable to set up bootstrap uCode : -5

[ 5553.340262] iwl3945 000: 02 : 00 : 0 : Unable to initialize device after 5 attempts
```

I would like to know if there is a way not to reinstall elementary (and how). Thank you!

Comment: If you can't even boot there's no way to solve this issue without a live usb. So I recommend you just install Juno directly. You can boot the "try elementary" mode so that you can backup any important file that you may have in your pc. By the way, don't worry if it's freezing while installing 1500+ updates. The update process is really resource intensive and can leave your system unusable for a while.

Comment: Since then, I could access the command line with the advanced options of elementary (from a former version of elementary in a recovery mode, in the avanced options of elementary). I could finish the upgrade process to Juno, all commands, even deleting pearl modules. Now I know how to access commands in text mode, could someone tell me how to use the boot repair command, I really am a Linux newbie and I would appreciate any help, thank you.